# Keep divs in one line after resizing

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have problem with my `divs` position. I coded website here is a link [www.szafortest.pl](http://www.szafortest.pl). I have gallery. This gallery is made from `divs` and I resize it by jquery. Problem is that sometimes after resizing one of divs fall down for a moment. Container with `divs` is `1010 px` width. All `divs` after resize has about `1250 px` width and this is a problem. How to prevent div falling down?

Comment: Please add you code.

Answer (score 1):

You div is falling when TWO divs are still animating. I see that in your slide.js you have used `.hover()` and `.animate()` your divs.

You have already used .stop() methods but that's not helping. Pass two `true` params.

Like `$this.stop(true, true).animate({ .. your code .. });`

This should solve your div falling issue.

Read more about .stop() here - https://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 0):

if you mean the Container class="categoryConntainer" take a look at here. http://prntscr.com/77zs60 It doesnt cover your gallery. all you have to do is to give a height of 100%. http://prntscr.com/77zsnj